# Spring Batch re-run steps multiple times on a schdeule

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have configured a Scheduler to invoke my job at a specific interval ( for testing purposes I have tried with 30-second intervals). It is successfully invoking the job without any issue. But once the job execution is a success during the first run It does not re-run the step again( Although I have passed a new job parameter in each invoke). I want to run the same step even it is completed as there might be new data in the source DB. I have tried

> .allowStartIfComplete(true)

But It did not invoke the reader in the step.

the primary requirement is to rerun the same batch job steps either it is exited successfully or not

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=30*1000)
@SchedulerLock(name = "job-1", lockAtLeastFor = "15S", lockAtMostFor = "20S")
public void batchJob() throws InterruptedException {
JobParameters Parameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
    .addLong("startAt", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
try {
    jobLauncher.run(job, Parameters);
} catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException
    | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

```
     // Executes the job
  @Bean
  public Job jobUpdate(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("employee")
        .listener(listener)
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step1)
        .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .allowStartIfComplete(true)
        .<Employee, Employee>chunk(2)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(httpClientExceptionSkipper())
        .writer(compositeItemWriter())
        .build();
  }
```

After the Initial run below is from the console log

```
2021-11-30 14:40:29.731  INFO --- o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler : Executing step: [step1]
2021-11-30 14:40:29.747  INFO --- o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep : Step: [step1] executed in 16ms
2021-11-30 14:40:29.752  INFO --- l.d.d.b.n.JobCompletionNotificationListener : !!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results
2021-11-30 14:40:29.756  INFO --- o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher$1 : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=employee]] completed with the following
```

Really Appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @StepScope to the reader bean that you have used in the step1 method.

It should work.